# connecting to whatsappweb with casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, whatsapp

When trying to connect to whatsapp web via casperJs I manage to get to a loading page but no further.
I've already connected to a whatsapp account through a phone and now I'm just copying the request headers when navigating to the page with casper.
It successfully finds #app but #pane-side never seems to load. When looking at a dev tools through chrome I see a lot of extra requests are made after the initial call to whatsapp so I'm thinking casper isn't loading a js script or something properly.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start().thenOpen('https://web.whatsapp.com/', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": 1,
        "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36", 
        "X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id": "reallyLongHexString"
    }
}, function() {
    this.echo('attempting to visit whatsapp');
});

casper.wait(5000, function() {
    this.echo("I've waited for 5 seconds");
})

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo('First Page: ' + this.getTitle());
    this.capture('0_firstpage.png');
});

casper.waitForSelector('#initial_startup', 
    function() { 
        this.echo('made it to initial_startup | startup.png');
        this.captureSelector('1_startup.png', '#app');
    }, 
    function() { 
        this.echo('timeout failed after 5 seconds');
    },
    5000);

casper.waitForSelector('#app', 
    function() { 
        this.echo('made it to "app" | whatsapp.png');
        this.captureSelector('2_whatsapp.png', '#app');
    }, 
    function() { 
        this.echo('timeout failed after 5 seconds');
    },
    5000);

casper.waitForSelector('#pane-side', 
    function() { 
        this.echo('made it to "pane-side" | messages.png');
        this.captureSelector('3_messages.png', '#app');
    }, 
    function() { 
        this.echo('timeout failed after 15 seconds');
    },
    15000);

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo('End of script: ' + this.getTitle());
    this.capture('4_end.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Above is the full script. Let me know what you think.
thanks